# Unintuitive behavior with $uses inheritance in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I ran into a problem the other day where the `PagesController` was throwing the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   find() on a non-object in
>   /home/jmccreary/www/thoroughbredsource.com/cakephp/app/app_controller.php
>   on line 20

**app_controller.php line 20:**

```
$this->current_user = $this->User->find('first', array('recursive' => 0,
  'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->logged_in_user_id)));
```

In this case `$this` was an instance of `PagesController`, but for whatever reason had not inherited the `User` model from app_controller.php.

For completeness, here's the relevant code:

**pages_controller.php**

```
var $name = 'Pages';
var $uses = null;

function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow('*');
}
```

**app_controller.php**

```
var $uses = array('User');
var $components = array('Session', 'Cookie', 'RequestHandler', 'DebugKit.Toolbar', 'Auth' => array('autoRedirect' => false, 'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'), 'flashElement' => 'error', 'loginError' => 'The username or password you provided are incorrect.', 'authError' => 'Please log in first.', 'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'passwd'), 'userScope' => array('User.active' => 1)));
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // configure Cookie Component
    // ...

    $this->logged_in_user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if ($this->logged_in_user_id) {
        // NOTE: the following runs on each request for the logged in user
        $this->current_user = $this->User->find('first', array('recursive' => 0, 'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->logged_in_user_id)));
    }
}
```

I got past this error by change `var $uses = null;` to `var $uses = array();`. Note that removing this line completely resulted in the same error.

In the end, I don't fully understand the original problem or my solution. I would appreciate a better explanation or what the appropriate solution should be. BTW, running CakePHP 1.3.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Controller class' source source which you can see at http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/controller/:

```
/**
 * An array containing the class names of models this controller uses.
 *
 * Example: `var $uses = array('Product', 'Post', 'Comment');`
 *
 * Can be set to array() to use no models.  Can be set to false to
 * use no models and prevent the merging of $uses with AppController
 *
 * @var mixed A single name as a string or a list of names as an array.
 * @access protected
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/view/961/components-helpers-and-uses
 */
    var $uses = false;
```

By using `$uses = array()`, you're telling the PagesController to "use no model and merge with AppController' $uses" so it works. You can see the merge in the source code starting on line 399. From what I can see, it treats "null" the same as "false" which means that it won't load any model including the ones from the AppController.

You can also see http://book.cakephp.org/view/961/components-helpers-and-uses for additional information on `$uses`.

Comment: +1 IMO, it's an almost disturbing usurpation of how OOP normally works.

Comment: Strange is line 427: `elseif ($this->uses !== null || $this->uses !== false) { $merge[] = 'uses'; }` The use of `||` here -- instead of `&&` -- will always result in `true`

Comment: @webbiedave - You're not reading it right. It says: if it's null or if it's false. In other words, it treats null the same as if it were false in this case. And like I said, if it's false, it doesn't merge with the AppController. Therefore, if null equals false than null means that it won't be merge either.

Comment: +1 thanks and sorry for not RTFM. I agree with **webbiedave** though, this seems to break traditional OOP *inheritance*. Whether that's PHP as a language or CakePHP is another story.

Comment: @Francois: What possible value could `$this->uses` have in which the above condition will result in false?

Comment: @Jason - CakePHP breaks traditional OOP inheritance.

Comment: @webbiedave - My bad! You're absolutely right. For some reason I thought I saw === (not !==).

Comment: Fair enough. Good discussion. @webbidave, you should submit line 427 for review on [CakePHP Lighthouse](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard)

Comment: Meh - if you override a member variable from a parent class in a subclass you never get a merged value without coding for that. In that way I guess you can say it isn't normal inheritance but if you set the value to null in a child controller why would you expect that same variable to be an array with a value further up the chain? The merging here in the case of an empty array is the only 'weird' thing going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending the AppController and then setting the uses variable to false/null which tells it to NOT use any models at all.

If you set it to an empty array( ) you will get an empty array from your PagesController merged with the array from the AppController and it will behave as expected.

This is *clearly* documented in the manual.

Comment: Got it. **Francois Deschenes** already provided that answer above, which I accepted.